# name of the attribute where the value is "true"

Tags: xml, xpath

I'm facing some xpath challenges. I need to get the name of the attribute which has the value true using xpath, but I can't seem to find a proper way to do it.

```
<vermarktungsart ERBPACHT="false" KAUF="true" MIETE_PACHT="false" />
```

in this case, the result should be "KAUF".

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this way :

```
name(//@*[.='true'])
```

**<kbd>[`xpathtester demo`](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/35d19ff821e05d667d2d515eda7a6998)</kbd>**

**output :**

```
KAUF
```

Comment: Hey, that's not a `<kbd>`.... but, really: Perfect answer.  Nice presentation.  +1

Comment: @kjhughes Thanks. The `<kbd>` thing is not my original idea, I followed some SQL Server guy that used to use `<kbd>` to decorate his `sqlfiddle.com` demo link. Credit goes to him :)